# How to use JavaScript variable on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have Bootstrap tabs on my web page.

On first tab, user is given is select route option. User select route. After their selection, AJAX request gets sent to save the route. On AJAX success, JavaScript close the first tab and automatically open the next.

On the next tab, I am using SQL select Query. Query will get details of route which user as selected in previous tab.

How I can use the ID of route which user selected in first tab into MySQL query. Select Query will something like SELECT * routedetails where RouteID =?. How can replace the? With the route ID

When user selects route; this is JavaScript.

```
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    // capture the ID of clicked route
                    $(".collection-routeselection").click( function(){
                        route_id = $(this).attr("value");

                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: '../data/collecting.php?action=route-selection',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'text',
                            data: {'routeid':route_id},
                            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                $("#tab1").removeClass("active");
                                $("#tab2").addClass("active");
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                //Display error message to user
                                alert("An error occured when saving the data");
                            }
                        });

                    });

                });
```

As you can see, in Ajax success, I close the current tab and open the next tab.

This is SELECT query on the same page but in different tab. I want to base results on the selected route.

```
FROM *routedetails WHere id_rou =?
```

How can I use the JavaScript variable (which holds the route ID) in PHP SQL statement on WHERE clause.

**EDIT:**

```
  case 'route-selection':


        $insert_web1 = $mysqli_scs->prepare("INSERT INTO collectiontracking_ctr (idrou_ctr,tab_ctr,created_ctr,modified_ctr) VALUES (?,'tab1',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

         //bind paramaters
        $rouid = "";
        if (isset($_POST['routeid'])) {

            $rouid = $_POST['routeid'];

        }

        $insert_web1->bind_param("i",$rouid);

        //Execute the statement
        $insert_web1->execute();



        //Echo the results so application can proceed
        echo '{"success":"true"}';
        break;
```

Comment: It sounds like `route_id` is the value you're looking for.  Which you already have, and even set to the value of `#selectedrouteid`.  It's not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: @David. I do have route id saved in JavaScript variable. My problem is how I can use the JavScript variable which has the route ID; in PHP SQL Select query.

Comment: Then where is your PHP code?  Where are you trying to use it?  You'd use it like any other `$_POST` data in PHP.  If you want to modify the code in `collecting.php` to use the value you're sending it then you'll have to look at the code in `collecting.php`, not the code that sends it the value.

Comment: @David. I have edited my question. Look under Edit heading. When Ajax request is call, this is where my PHP code is.

Comment: Can you dump the contents of `$_POST` and see what it contains?  Also take a look at `file_get_contents('php://input')` to see if the data being sent by AJAX is in the request body instead of the request values.  Anything sent by the client in a POST request should be in one of those two places.  If it isn't, there's something else wrong that's not being shared here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<?php
    $routeId = $_REQUEST["routeid"];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).attr("value");` should be `$(this).val()`.

The `value` attribute is the original default value of the input in the HTML. `.val()` gets the value property that the user has edited.